# Pourquoi « elles » est-il le mot correct dans cette phrase : « Elles ne peuvent être installées » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, informatique

Mon ordinateur a montré une boîte de dialogue et il y est dit « elles ne peuvent être installées ». Pourquoi est-ce que « elles » est le mot correct dans cette phrase ? Le mot « elles » n'est-il pas censé être réservé aux femmes ?

Comment: Le message était-il simplement "lles ne peuvent pas être installées", ou y avait-il un autre mesage ou une autre boite de dialogue avant ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non, *elles* n'est pas réservé aux femmes mais fait référence à tout nom féminin qui peut parfois désigner un homme et souvent un objet ou un concept, forcément asexués.

Dans l'exemple de la question, il est très peu vraisemblable que *elles* représente des femmes puisqu'une femme ne peut pas vraiment être « installée dans un ordinateur », pas plus qu'un homme d'ailleurs.

Il s'agit donc de quelque chose que l'on peut envisager d'installer en informatique comme :

> Elles (les applications, images, données, etc.) ne peuvent être installées.

Comment: Pourquoi n'y avait-il pas de mot *pas* dans la phrase?

Comment: @CarlMasens Le *pas* est optionnel ici, le *ne* étant suffisant pour indiquer la négation (registre soutenu). En français parlé, on aurait pu ne pas utiliser *ne* et seulement *pas* : *Elles peuvent pas être installées* mais cette forme n'est pas utilisée à l'écrit.